# maven: fetch resources from network during build

Tags: maven

I found this nice plugin: http://evgeny-goldin.com/wiki/Copy-maven-plugin

As it is a one man show, and support might be dropped over years, I wonder if there is a standard way to fetch resources from the network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also:

- http://mojo.codehaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/download-single-mojo.html
- https://github.com/maven-download-plugin/maven-download-plugin
- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/ with http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html

Is the resource a dependency? If so:

- http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html